# Can I use function parameter in this.state path as wildcard? EX. this.state.{parameter}.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to use function parameter as wildcard in paths?

addStorage function should raise amount of product it receives by one. It works if I hardcode some product in the path, but I can't use "receivedKey" as wildcard in the path. Is it possible to do or should it it be done in some other way?

I have tried so far storage2.{receivedkey}.amount but it didn't work. I tried all possible variants of using brackets and googled but nothing works so far.

```
// Adds product to storage
addStorage = receivedKey => {
    const storage2 = this.state.storage;
    storage2.coffeemaker.amount = storage2.coffeemaker.amount + 1;
    this.setState({ storage: storage2 });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
// Adds product to storage
addStorage = receivedKey => {
    const storage2 = this.state.storage;
    storage2[receivedKey].amount = storage2[receivedKey].amount + 1;
    this.setState({ storage: storage2 });
};
```